# Horizontal Scroll on a webpage not working in iOS

Tags: html, ios

Please check the following website on a desktop browser. 
http://www.onebyinfinity.co.nz/m/ - You'll see a horizontal scroll bar

But when opened on an iPad or iPhone, the horizontal scroll does not work. The website's horizontal scroll works fine on Android browser, however on the iOS devices, Safari refuses to scroll horizontally when the user swipes left and right.

Is there anything I need to do to enable horizontal scroll on iOS safari? Please note I do not wan't a swipe event (I have already done that on the home page of the website, I'm not happy with the performance). I just want the scrollbar to work as expected.

Thanks, 
Arun.

Comment: maybe you want the jquery plugin. touchswipe http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/touchSwipe/demos/ very awesome for mobile devices

Comment: I have done that on the home page of the website. That works but its not smooth. So I added this page. It works very nicely in Android, but not on iOS.

Comment: I doubt you have tried the plugin @KeesSonnema linked. It's a very nice one. Even better than Tiny Scrollbar (because there are more events supported)

Comment: Brainfeeder, on the home page of this website, I have trapped a swipe event and am manually scrolling the page, by changing the left margin. You can see the animation in the desktop browser when you press the left or right arrow keys. My client is not happy with that. I'm only asking why the iOS browser not scroll horizontally like an Android browser.

Comment: @Arun In Firefox there is no scrolling when I use left or right arrows. And in the photo gallery, if you click the down button, the next horizontal scrollbar isn't visible (it falls off screen). So I can't scroll there.
And maybe if you put some of your code here we could help you on the why-iOS-safari-does-not-scroll ..
Just saying that if you use a ready made plugin you will have less trouble to make the website on all platforms.

Comment: @Arun Now it does work with the arrows :)  But why is your client not happy with that ? If it works on mobile it's a great website like that. I would be happy with the design...

Answer (score 0):

For the swipe events to trigger you need the [jQuery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) library. Or use a plugin like [Tiny Scrollbar](http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/), which is probably a more suitable solution for your website, since it allready has the mobile support build in.

Comment: I have done that on the home page of the website. That works but its not smooth. So I added this page. It works very nicely in Android, but not on iOS.

Comment: i use this on my website and it works great  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">