# Can't horizontally scroll in Ionic 1.3.0 iOS App

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, horizontal-scrolling

My Cordova/Ionic (v1.3.0) App consists primarily of a JQuery App that builds the HTML for complex forms. The same JQuery App is used to build the complex forms for the web browser with only a few places where it inserts mobile-specific code.

I am now trying to have a horizontally scrolling table section within the vertically scrolling form (the form itself doesn't scroll horizontally, just the table section). The section horizontal scrolling works in Safari/Chrome/Firefox on the computer, in Safari on iOS, and in the Android version of our Cordova/Ionic app but it doesn't horizontally scroll in the iOS app.

I tried various fixes based on these SO questions and documentation ([q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30351672/how-to-make-an-ionic-content-scroll),[q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37230979/ionic-content-not-scrolling),[q3](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/horizontal-scroll-not-working-in-ios-10/63608),[q4](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/api/directive/ionContent/)) where I changed it from a `<div/>` to `<ion-content/>` and added the `overflow-scroll="true" direction="xy" delegate-handle="tableGroup"` properties and called `$ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('tableGroup').resize()` after the JQuery app loaded but nothing worked. I also tried using TinyScrollbar based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15928000/horizontal-scroll-on-a-webpage-not-working-in-ios) but that wasn't loading right. So I've tried going many directions but haven't gotten anywhere. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured this out on my own. I put a couple variations of a simple scrolling elements in containers on the Ionic page and `<ion-scroll/>` worked. Then I tried putting it in the JQuery app with a delegate handle `sectionScroll` and called `$ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('sectionScroll').resize();` after the JQuery app loaded but got a console warning saying that it couldn't find anything named `sectionScroll` and that I should put it in a `$timeout()`. I tried that but it still didn't work. Then I realized that since `<ion-scroll/>` is an angular directive that is created as part of a long template string inserted into the Ionic app using JQuery, it needed to be compiled by Angular to be recognized as below:

```
let toCompile = angular.element('#formContent');
let linkFn = $compile(toCompile);
linkFn($scope);
$ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('sectionScroll').resize();
```